# Trying to remove element based on type of attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove an element based on type of attribute. It isn't working for some reason.

The element in question is this:

```
<p style="width:250px;font-size:11px;text-align:left;margin-left:1.2ex;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;line-height:1.15em;">–&nbsp;in Europe<span style="font-size:8px;"><span style="white-space:nowrap;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>(<span style="font-size:9px;">green &amp;&nbsp;dark grey</span>)<br>
–&nbsp;in the European Union<span style="font-size:8px;"><span style="white-space:nowrap;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span>(<span style="font-size:9px;">green</span>)</p>
```

I am trying to remove it this way - item is a container element.

```
$(item).find("p").filter("[style]").remove();
```

There are no other `<p>` tags with the attribute style, however this doesn't appear to remove it.

Other code, like this, works fine:

```
$(item).find(".reference").remove();
```

How do I remove all p tags with the style attribute from the item element?

This is how item is created:

```
                                $.get(link, function(response) {
                                        var elements = $.parseHTML(response);
                                        var wiki = $(elements).find('#mw-content-text').find("p");
                                        //var ps = [];
                                        var arrayLength = wiki.length;
                                        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                                            if (wiki[i].innerHTML === "") {
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            var item = wiki[i];
```

The link variable is a link to wikipedia.

Comment: whether the style is added dynamically?

Comment: please provide demo that replicates this. We can't see what `item` is so it could be different than expected. Does `$(item).find("p")` work?

Comment: Yes, $(item).find("p") works

Comment: then if the filter isn't working it sounds like the style doesn't exist when you run your code. Is something changing the style elsewhere in the code base? Also can check this by running your remove code in browser console. Should work there if you can see the style

Comment: you cut off the ajax code before showing how you use `remove()`. Since `item` will change on every iteration of `for` loop that could be a problem

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
$.each(item.children('p'), function(index) {
  if ($(this).attr('style')) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

item refers to p element itself. you don't have to find p in item:

```
$(item).filter("[style]").remove();
```

Comment: `item is a container element.`??

Comment: The element in question refering to item is `p` tag element

Answer (score 0):

after re-looking over your question ,

```
$(item).find("p").filter("[style]").remove();
```

is perfectly valid , instead of trying to come up with alternative ways to write it , find out what is wrong with `item`, because it is not what you think it is if above code is not working

Comment: this will break badly if `item` is an object and there is no reason it would work if `find().filter()` doesn't